# In Delphi XE2, Uploading to azure get stuck forever, how solve?

Tags: delphi, azure, delphi-xe2, azure-storage

I'm uploading images from Delphi XE2 to azure.

This is what I do:

```
var
  RespInfo: TCloudResponseInfo;
  Headers: TStringList;
  FileName: String;
  Content : TBytes;
begin
      FHost.PutBlockBlob(FContainer,FileName, Content, EmptyStr, Headers,
        nil, RespInfo);
```

In PutBlockBlob get stuck forever when uploading some files a bit big (ie > 1mb).

What I can do?

PD: A sample image that get stuck (is random, somethimes it upload other not. The majority of the times not.)

http://bestseller.blob.core.windows.net/superventas/122021.jpg

Comment: Provide more info. You've not provided anything that will help us figure out what's causing the problem. A random chunk of code without any more information isn't very useful, since we can't see your other code or know anything else about your system from here. :)

Comment: This is the only code that cause the trouble. Only happend if the file is "big". Is reduced to the only place where is stuck.

Comment: I can't check anything. I never pass PutBlockBlob!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Delphi. For troubleshooting this issue, you can try to use Visual Studio and C# to upload the blob, if it works fine, the issue may be related to Delphi side. If it is unable to make it work in Visual Studio either, I suggest you to use Fiddler to monitor the request to see what might be incorrect. For instructions about uploading blobs using C#, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651129.aspx.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.